# How to run angularjs app on node server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have make a angularjs app and run it on wamp server its running fine but now want to move it on node express but after reading about that i just made change in my package.json file which is as follow:

```
      {
        "name": "Example",
         "namelower": "example",
          "version": "0.0.1",
           "description": "An example AngularJS project",
           "readme": "README.md",
           "repository": {
           "type": "git",
           "url": "git@git.example.com:example.git"
            },
           "devDependencies": {
                        "grunt": "0.4.2",
                        "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.3.0",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.8.0",
"grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "0.3.0",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.2.2",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "0.5.3",
"grunt-exec": "0.4.5",
"grunt-jsdoc": "0.5.4",
"grunt-karma": "0.8.3",
"karma": "0.12.16",
"karma-jasmine": "0.1.5",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.1.4"

     },
         "scripts": {
          "postinstall": "bower install",
           "test": "grunt build"
                      },

           "dependencies": {
                               "protractor": "^2.1.0"
                                "express"    : "~4.7.2",
                                "mongoose"   : "~3.6.2",
                                 "morgan"     : "~1.2.2",
                                "body-parser": "~1.5.2",
                               "method-override": "~2.1.2"
                                      }
                                     }
```

after editing package.json i ran npm install on cmd but get this

```
         error:C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App>npm install
         npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
         npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
         npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program          Files\\nod
```

\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
            npm ERR! node v0.12.7
            npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
           npm ERR! file C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App\package.json
           npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

```
       npm ERR! Failed to parse json
        npm ERR! Unexpected token 'e' at 34:6
        npm ERR!     "express"    : "~4.7.2",
        npm ERR!      ^
        npm ERR! File: C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App\package.json
          npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
        npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
        npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file.  JSON.parse

       npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
       npm ERR!  C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App\npm-debug.log
```

how can i do this and what other changes i need to run my app on node express??

Comment: It seems like you `package.json` is broken. I.e. you most likely have some syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `"protractor": "^2.1.0"` on line 33.

If you can instead of writing your package.json by hand use `npm init` and then install all the packages from the console using `--save`.  That way you avoid typos.

Comment: what other changes i make to run my app on express ?

Comment: @Hassan just make sure you install angular with bower and configure the `.bowerrc` to make your path correct.  That and you may need a package called 'body-parser' to access data passed in post requests to the server.

Comment: i install npm for mode server following this but still not able to run my app on nodejs server https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular

Comment: I wrote a reference guide for myself a while back, maybe it will help you: http://smarturl.it/MEAN

Answer (score 0):

#### Steps to deploy an AngularJs App on local server using Node.js

1. First open `cmd` in your Application Path then type `npm init`. Supply the necessary information.
2. Install express using `npm i express` and create `server.js` file like below:

   ```
   const express = require('express')
   const app = express();
   const port = 3000;
   var path    = require("path");

   app.get('/',function(req,res){  
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html')); 
    });

   app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
   ```
3. Open http://localhost:3000/ to see the output. It will render `index.html`.